# Запись python словаря в postgres

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, dict

Существует словарь python, который динамически меняется в связи с этим его парсинг и сохранение по полям не возможны.

Существует ли вариант сохранить словарь целиком и в случае падения приложения точно также считать его из postgresql и восстановить.

Comment: а вопрос в чём - как хранить или как писать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150617/adding-dict-object-to-postgresql

Comment: Если по элементам словаря не нужна фильтрация на уровне СУБД, только сохранить/загрузить, то проще всего сериализовать его в строку и сохранить в поле типа TEXT.